# Add IF IE Conditional Dynamically

Tags: asp.net

Is is possible to add

```
<!--[if IE 6]> ....  <![endif]-->
```

On dynamically generated css or js file reference.

e.g

```
HtmlGenericControl ie6css = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
ie6css.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
ie6css.Attributes.Add("src", Config.GetUrl("ie6/ie6-min.css"));
Page.Header.Controls.Add(ie6css);
```

will generate

```
<link href="ie6/ie6-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I need to enclose generated css reference in some conditional statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can [read browser info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) from `Request.Browser` in your server side code, and load content based on that. I'm not sure how dependable that is, and it's easily faked, so I would only rely on it for style things (like it seems you're doing).

You could also [detect the browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) on the client side via JavaScript, then [dynamically load style sheets](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out Conditionizr, it does all this stuff for you, exactly what you need for every browser/platform/device, even latest browsers and legacy:

http://conditionizr.com